# scantxoutset timing out

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, python, utxo-set, scantxoutset

I have extremely simple python code to use scantxoutset.

The problem is that when I debug in pycharm it keeps timing out.

```python
rpc_connection = rpcConnector.rpcConnect()

json_req = [{"desc": "addr(1K6KoYC69NnafWJ7YgtrpwJxBLiijWqwa6)"}]

tx_scan = rpc_connection.scantxoutset("start", json_req)
```

If I run without debugging, the script finishes before scantxoutset returns anything.

Am I using this incorrectly?